# Animate element of svg image in css

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to animate some elements of an image in svg. To test the animation I first tried it on the whole image to check that it works well (it does). But when I change the class `state-indicator-illustration` by the id `note-double-1` (id of the element to animate) the element `note-double 1` disappears completely without me understanding why.I specify that to test I inserted the image "line by line" in the HTML code.

Here is the code (i put jsfiddle to avoid very long message) :

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pju2ateL/2/

Thanks for your help,
elshiri.

Comment: If you remove the transform attribute of the path the animation is working. As an observation: you have lots of transformations moving the shapes to and fro.

Comment: i tried it  : https://jsfiddle.net/014psox2/2/ and its still not working

Answer (score 1):

As I've commented:  you need to remove the transform attribute of the path.
In order to preserve your transformations I am wrapping the path in a group and transform the group instead of transforming the path. Also I had to change the viewBox since otherwise the path falls outside the svg canvas.

As you can see the css animation is working.

```css
/* .state-indicator-illustration is working */
#note-double-1 {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  transform: translateY(0px);
  animation: float 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes float {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="244" height="149.388" viewBox="-15 -320 244 149.388">          
  <g id="off" transform="translate(-1090, -390)">                  
    <g transform="translate(-28.904 -320.214)" >
      <path id="note-double-1" d="M1114.926,434.328l5.138-22.688,22.647,1.41c-.05.226-.093.412-.133.6q-2.918,12.882-5.824,25.761a5.089,5.089,0,0,1-3.018,3.727,7.907,7.907,0,0,1-9.016-2.153c-2.277-2.776-1.476-6.41,1.8-7.774a7.7,7.7,0,0,1,8.184,1.341c.1.083.205.172.31.245h.067l3.237-14.3c-1.28-.081-2.527-.164-3.772-.245-4.355-.272-8.713-.535-13.066-.821-.412-.029-.524.113-.61.49-1.4,6.229-2.861,12.445-4.2,18.686a5.393,5.393,0,0,1-4.558,4.48,7.783,7.783,0,0,1-8.129-3.455,4.664,4.664,0,0,1,1.414-6.408,7.077,7.077,0,0,1,6.186-.777,8.54,8.54,0,0,1,1.767.758A17.8,17.8,0,0,1,1114.926,434.328Z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks it working for the single element. But the animation aim is to keep all the image and make only this element move. But, when i take your html and css code and i add all the paths around the element is still lonely (the rest of the image needs to be static)